# Attach native application via JNI to already running JVM on Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm, java-native-interface, native

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441878/attach-to-already-running-jvm) has already been answered for Windows, but I could not find out how to achieve the same on Linux.

I want to deepen my knowledge in JNI. I already got JNI projects working with [`JNI_CreateJavaVM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp16334), creating a new JVM from within the native application.

But this time I would like to *not* create the JVM within the native application (i.e., *not* using [`JNI_CreateJavaVM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp16334)), but to attach to an already running one (i.e., using [`AttachCurrentThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread) on a VM that has been started before the native application by some `java myApplication` call).

Is there a way on Linux how to achieve this? I need to get a `JavaVM` object of the running JVM. I tried to use [`JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp633), but this does not return any JVMs (I think this method only returns VMs created by the current process, e.g., by using [`JNI_CreateJavaVM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp16334), and not all VMs that are running on the system)

Comment: When you create a JVM it is running in your current process as a part of your memory space. What do you mean by attach? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I now changed the question a bit to make my goals more clear hopefully. What I want to achieve is to _attach_ (`AttachCurrentThread`) to an already running VM. I need to get this VM's `JavaVM` object for this, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can't move a thread from one process to another or share threads between processes. No OS that I know of will allow this. So it's not clear to me what you expect attach to do. You can create a TCP connection to an existing process and manage it remotely but this is not JNI, it's TCP.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: For example, I would like to be able execute calls to some (static) methods within an already running JVM from my native application. I thought I could use JNI for this, by using JNI's `GetStaticMethodID` & `CallStaticIntMethod`, as I already did before in other projects. The only difference is that the JVM would already be running this time, and not created within the native application using `JNI_CreateJavaVM` as in my older projects.
Basically, with "attach", I mean that I want to obtain "JNI-access" to an already running JVM (i.e., retrieve its `JNIEnv` and `JavaVM` objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI functions can be used only within the process that started JVM. JNI does not allow you to control other processes.

However, there is a way to load your code in the context of different JVM process using HotSpot Dynamic Attach API.

- Compile your code into an agent library (.so);
- Create [Agent_OnAttach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#onattach) function that will be an entry point for your code;
- Load the agent library using Dynamic Attach.

There is [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) to attach to remote JVM and to [load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#loadAgentPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) agent library in its context. But you can also do it from native code like in my [`jattach`](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) project.

Comment: Dynamic Attach API is the way I then used yesterday, thanks for the answer! And I will surely look into jattach!

Comment: You also can use [jvm-attach](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/jvm-attach) which is a wrapper for jattach, then you can attach programatically from Java

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to make calls from one OS process (your native application) to a separate OS process (running a java application).  You can't make "direct" calls to a JVM in another process.  You need to use some sort of remote protocol.  Two "builtin" options are JMX (via RMI) or straight RMI.  Alternately, you could expose a webservice on the other JVM and invoke it using standard HTTP interactions.